# SSL and Non Secure items message

Tags: ssl, https

I am seeing the "This Page contains both secure and nonsecure items." message when viewing a page on my site from with IE 6. This does not appear in both IE 7 or Firefox. I have done some research and it appears that the problem has to do with links to HTTP:// rather than HTTPS://

Would the fix just be to view the page source and find everywhere there is an HTTP:// src and change it? I believe they are being generated from JavaScript.

Thanks Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO the problem was that a 3rd party control was creating an  element with and attribute src="about:blank". In IE6 this src is not trusted. The resolution for me was to create a blank.htm file. This file contained nothing but an  tag.

I then set the

This fixed the issue. From what I have read, this is not a problem in newer versions of IE.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to make sure that scripts and images are referenced via HTTPS, if the page is referenced by HTTPS.

Alternatively, try using relative URLs, so that your page can be either HTTP or HTTPS without requiring the html to change.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running prototype.js?

There's a line in there to detect when the page has loaded which calls \: as a src=

Replace this src with a js file on your system. It can be blank.